# How do I get jinja to work on my html web page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

The table I am trying to fetch data from and put on the html web page is called "Conservative" but  none of the data appears on the web page where I have put the jinja variables.
Here is the flask code:

```
@app.route("/consrecommend")
@login_required
def consrecommend():
"""Show Conservative Recommendations"""
user_id = session["user_id"]
contransactions = db.execute("SELECT name, percentage, investment FROM conservative WHERE 
                              user_id = ?", user_id)

for i in range(len(contransactions)):
    contransactions[i]["investment"] = usd(contransactions[i]["investment"])
return render_template("consrecommend.html", contransactions=contransactions)
```

No data from database "Conservative" shows up on the html web page.  Here is the jinja code on web page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Conservative Portfolio Recommendation
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
   <table>
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>Investment</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {% for contransaction in contransactions %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ contransaction["name"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["percentage"] }} </td>
                <td> {{ contransaction["investment"] }} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table><br><br>
    <center><img class="img-scale" src="{{ static('/images/consport.jpg') }}" 
             alt="Conservative Portfolio" /></center>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data in `contransactions`, please check that and inform me! And if possible provide an example by [edit]ing your question. [mre] is necessary while asking question here.

Comment: I am very new to all this, but when I say "contransactions = db.execute("SELECT name, percentage, investments FROM conservative WHERE user_id = ?", user_id), doesn

Comment: Doesn..........?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't name, percentage, and investment from table conservative populate contransactions?  The table conservative has data in the name field, percentage field, and  the investment field.

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 9, Total: 10 (Query took 0 sec)
SELECT * FROM "conservative" LIMIT 0, 30

← T → id user_id name percentage investment
 Edit Delete 1 NULL Blue Chip Growth 15 100000
 Edit Delete 2 NULL Large Cap Value 15 100000
 Edit Delete 3 NULL Dividend Yield 10 100000
 Edit Delete 4 NULL Mid Cap 5 100000
 Edit Delete 5 NULL Government Bond 10 100000
 Edit Delete 6 NULL Income Fund 10 100000
 Edit Delete 7 NULL Balanced Fund 10 100000
 Edit Delete 8 NULL Total Return Fund 10 100000
 Edit Delete 9 NULL Government Money Market 10 100000
 Edit Delete 10 NULL Money Market 5 100000

Comment: No `.fetchall()` after your `db.execute()`?  If you `print()` after pulling from the database are you seeing the results you want?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're using `SQLite3`.

In sqlite3, if you are using `cur.execute` function, it will return `sqlite3.Cursor`, which is an `iterator`. And you can directly use for loop with this returned object.

Do remember, since this is an iterator, you will lose all the data once you read it.

So you have to save the data while you are reading. That's why you need to use `.fetchall()`, which will return the list of queryset.

Note:
If you're using another db like postgres, `pscopg2.cursor.execute` function won't return anything like `sqlite3.Cursor` in sqlite, so you can't able to run the loop directly. You should call `.fetchall()` function.

Comment: Thank you.  I used .fetchall() function and it worked at getting data from the database.  However, it still does not put the data into my html file using jinja.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I have it working now.